# How to control two scroll bars simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div's with horizontal scroll bars. If I scroll one the other one should also scroll simultaneously.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll 2 scrollbars with jquery the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389228/scroll-2-scrollbars-with-jquery-the-same-time)

Answer (score 3):

Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389228/scroll-2-scrollbars-with-jquery-the-same-time):

```
$('.linked').scroll(function(){
    $('.linked').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());    
})
```

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8Krz/) sample.